# Oracle STATS_MODE returning random(?) number

Tags: sql, oracle, statistics

I'm using `STATS_MODE` to get the mode of a column, I manually checked my data versus the result but there is no mode, every single value is unique.

So what does Oracle do when there is no mode? to me it looks like it's just returning a random number. Is there a way to just get the MAX value if there's no mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual does not clearly state that the behaviour is deterministic...

> STATS_MODE takes as its argument a set of values and returns the value
>   that occurs with the greatest frequency. If more than one mode exists,
>   then Oracle Database **chooses one and returns only that one value**.

You could easily test for this though, and return the max:

```
select stats_mode(n) as oracle_stats_mode
      ,case when count(n) = count(distinct n) -- If all records are unique
            then max(n)                       -- return the max
            else stats_mode(n)                -- else return oracle's stats_mode
         end as your_stats_mode
  from (select 1    as n from dual union all
        select 2    as n from dual union all
        --select 2    as n from dual union all
        --select null as n from dual union all
        select 3    as n from dual
       );
```

Try with and without the repeated n=2 and n=null. Also beware that count(*) and count(n) will behave differently.

Comment: I ended up fixing my problem by using your query, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`stats_mode` will returns the value that occurs several time, so if you have unique values why then you are using it ?. from the [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions154.htm) however you can adjust this query to get the max

```
SELECT commission_pct FROM
   (SELECT commission_pct, COUNT(commission_pct) AS cnt1 FROM employees
      GROUP BY commission_pct)
   WHERE cnt1 = 
      (SELECT MAX (cnt2) FROM
         (SELECT COUNT(commission_pct) AS cnt2
         FROM employees GROUP BY commission_pct));
```

Comment: Not all values are like this. I'm just questioning its behavior when all the values are unique. I'll try this query out, thanks, although it would have been better to avoid multiple subqueries like that.

Answer (score 0):

> So what does Oracle do when there is no mode?

If all the values of the column are `NULL`s `STATS_MODE`returns `NULL`.

If **at least one value exists in the column `MODE`always exists**.

In some cases there are more keys with the hignest frequency (aka MODE). In this case some (non deterministic) value of those keys is returned. So you may observe random behaviour, but limited to the keys with the highest frequency.

Answer (score 0):

use this :
When The Number of The Modes are the same the query return the higher number :

```
select **ABS(stats_mode(n*-1))** as oracle_stats_mode
      ,case when count(n) = count(distinct n) -- If all records are unique
            then max(n)                       -- return the max
            else stats_mode(n)                -- else return oracle's stats_mode
         end as your_stats_mode
  from (select 1    as n from dual union all
        select 2    as n from dual union all
        --select 2    as n from dual union all
        --select null as n from dual union all
        select 3    as n from dual
       );
```

Comment: Please provide more information to your code. :)